# Running tests in Chrome works fine, but Webkit and Firefox lead to the browser closing immediately after launch, using Playwright (macOS) locally

Tags: typescript, playwright

The errors are written as follows:
 `Error: worker process exited unexpectedly (code=null, signal=SIGABRT)`

Also

`When navigating to baseUrl. Something went wrong... The browser was closed. Error message: page.goto: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 310.)`

i have been updated libs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to your local proxy settings, check your proxy settings vs. test environment.

[Apple developer documentation about 310:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors/cferrorhttpsproxyconnectionfailure/)

> A connection couldn’t be established to the HTTPS proxy.